# Securing Facebook SDK Secret Key in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I keep reading that the Facebook SDK secret key should not be in your client-side code but I cannot find a tutorial on how to avoid doing this with the PHP SDK.

I'm not a seasoned developer so I'm struggling to translate the Facebook PHP SDK docs app security section into actual files and code.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you shouldn't hard-code authentication credentials like API keys into your code. You want to avoid doing something like this:

```
$key = 'my secret key';
```

Consider the case where you commit this file to a source code control system. Now your credentials are stored there permanently, and anybody who has read access to the repository can make API calls on your behalf.

Instead, store the credentials outside the code base for your project. For example:

```
$key = file_get_contents('/path/to/secret/key');
```

Make sure that the file `/path/to/secret/key` is not in the repository for this project. Now, when you commit your code, it doesn't contain the actual key, just a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is not client-side. Even if you write it in client files(like html), the PHP code you write inside the `<?php  ?>` tags will not be sent to the client. The server will execute it, so as long as your API key is in PHP code, it will not be readable by the client.

Edit: If you plan to push your code to GitHub so it's public and can be accessed by everyone, follow Alex Howansky's answer.